# Near real-time pub/sub solution sending emails&http requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, architecture, publish-subscribe

I am trying to architecture the best solution for being able to send email/http requests when something happens within my web api domain.
For example, when some entity change i want to send email/http notifications to potential subscribers.

There are options like:

1. use .NET static events within web api [don't like that one as its
   not scalable]
2. use MSSQL db to save messages and then use some service as a processor/sender [this one scales but i am concerned about SQL server & connections performance once load goes up]
3. Use Redis/RabbitMQ/etc as a queue and then again have service acting as processor/sender...[those i have no experience with]

Requirements are:

1. should be able to handle ~100 http requests per second at peek times (each request is very lightweight and will take very short time)
2. should be scalable so when i add new web app servers all work
3. the delay between domain event (entity state changed) and email/http request sent should be less than 10 secs
4. should have an option to lease message to processor so that if processor fails to delay it can do retries

Would appreciate any thoughts/ideas/experiences/points to good direction.

Thanks!

(update)
I actually think i made a mistake using a word 'subscribers' as it might mean something different in this context. So, when i said 'potential subscribers' i meant actual users that want to receive email notifications and i did not mean different processes that actually process queue entries (for example, windows services that do actual email sending).

So, in this context, i actually think i need one publisher (web api) and one subscriber (windows service) which brings me back to thinking i might need queues and not topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a topic instead of a queue?

RabbitMQ:  https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric52/index.jsp#com.vmware.vfabric.rabbitmq.2.8/rabbit-web-docs/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html

ActiveMQ:  http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html

It's usually pretty easy to hook a queue up to a topic so that you can have persistent queues for those applications that aren't online.

Comment: I haven't as i haven't worked with things like that so far so just didn't know what are best options to think about. From what i am just reading, seems like topics are great advice! thanks for that one!
Additionally, could you please explain a bit your last sentence? What do you mean by persistant queues for apps that are not online?
thanks

Comment: Oh, i now see i actually might have not used precise teeminology in my question. Please see my update in original question. Thanks

Comment: Based on your updates, I think choice #3 is by far your best bet.  This is what Queues are designed for.  Persistent queues are queues that have a persistent data store (usually a disk or database):  Here is Rabbit MQ's:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html.  Having a service listening on the other end is pretty straightforward, and you can find lots of examples on the web.

Comment: Great, then i'll dig into that docs. Thanks for reference. Implementation itself is not my main concern as that's what docs are for. The main thing for me was to hear about what to expect in terms of performance for requirements for number of messages & processing delay. Are those numbers something big, small, moderate in terms of RabbitMQ?

I will mark your answer as The Answer.
Thanks!